# SQL LIte, 2.8.6 Not Deleting entries from Tables

Tags: database, sqlite

I have this problem with SQL Lite, whereby my application updates the database successfully and everything is grand. I then access my SQLLite DB using SqlShell. I issue the following commands.

1. Delete from Table1
2. Delete from Table2
3. Delete from Table3

When I issue a Select * from Table1. I get no results returned from within SQLShell. Which is expected after issuing a delete statement. **However the size of my database file doesn't actually decrease as I would have expected it too.**

However when my app queries the tables, it finds results. All the results that I thought I deleted.

I know I am accessing the right database, because if I replace the existing database, with a completely empty version of the one my app is accessing. Then My app reports that there are no entries in the database.

Its almost as if my changes aren't getting committed or they're **being marked for deletion, and thus not shown**

Any light someone could shed on this would be greatly appreciated.